# How can I fix Cannot GET error in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I got a problem while learning basic express concepts. In this piece of code, where I am setting the route to my data JSON file everything works fine and I see the data.

```
app.get('/api/v1/tours', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    results: tours.length,
    data: {
      tours,
    },
  });
});
```

But when I am trying to set up id:

```
app.get('/api/v1/tours/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    // results: tours.length,
    // data: {
    //   tours,
    // },
  });
});
```

and test it in Postman and browser devtool with "/api/v1/tours/5" route, I am constantly getting "Cannot GET /api/v1/tours/5" error.

[Postman test. Browser devtools show the same thing]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2WET.png

Comment: Postman respond with 404 code which is 'Not Found'. Please check if that piece of data actually exist in the database or try to query another id. If neither of these solutions helped you, then check if you are actually can persist data into the database.

Comment: @Reborn it is still the same. If  I try to GET   only  "/api/v1/tours/", I receive the whole json file as it has to be. Including the element with an id of 5. But if I specify in my route "/api/v1/tours/:id"  and then try to GET "/api/v1/tours/5" or replace 5 with any other id from the json file in Postman or in the browser, I get only an error.

Comment: There might be an issue with data type of your index. For example, you request id = 5 where 5 is integer, meanwhile in your database id is something different.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to restart your express app? If, it solves your problem, you can use a [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) package for auto restart application.

Comment: I am actually already using a nodemon package. Restart doesn't help.